# SqlWorkflowInstanceStore WaitForEvents returns HasRunnableWorkflowEvent but LoadRunnableInstance fails

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

Dears

Please help me with restoring delayed (and persisted) workflows.

I'm trying to check on self-hosted workflow store is there any instance that was delayed and can be resumed. For testing purposes I've created dummy activity that is delayed and it persists on delay.

generally resume process looks like:

```
get WF definition
configure sql instance store 
call WaitForEvents
is there event with HasRunnableWorkflowEvent.Value name and if it is
create WorkflowApplication object and execute LoadRunnableInstance  method
```

it works fine if store is `created|initialized`, `WaitForEvents` is called, store is closed. In such case store reads all available workflows from persisted DB and throws timeout exception if there is no `workflows` available to resume.

The problem happens if store is created and loop is started only for `WaitForEvents` (the same thing happens with `BeginWaitForEvents`). In such case it reads all available `workflows` from `DB` (with proper IDs) but then instead of `timeout exception` it is going to read one more instance (I know exactly how many `workflows` is there ready to be resumed because using separate test `database`). But fails to read and `throws InstanceNotReadyException`. In `catch` I'm checking `workflowApplication.Id`, but it was not saved with my test before.

I've tried to run on new (empty) persistent database and result is the same :(

This code fails:

```
using (var storeWrapper = new StoreWrapper(wf, connStr))
    for (int q = 0; q < 5; q++)
    {
        var id = Resume(storeWrapper); // InstanceNotReadyException here when all activities is resumed
```

But this one works as expected:

```
for (int q = 0; q < 5; q++)
    using (var storeWrapper = new StoreWrapper(wf, connStr))
    {
        var id = Resume(storeWrapper); // timeout exception here or beginWaitForEvents continues to wait
```

What is a best solution in such case? Add empty `catch` for `InstanceNotReadyException` and ignore it?

Here are my tests

```
const int delayTime = 15;
string connStr = "Server=db;Database=AppFabricDb_Test;Integrated Security=True;";

[TestMethod]
public void PersistOneOnIdleAndResume()
{
    var wf = GetDelayActivity();

    using (var storeWrapper = new StoreWrapper(wf, connStr))
    {
        var id = CreateAndRun(storeWrapper);
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("done {0}", id));
    }

    using (var storeWrapper = new StoreWrapper(wf, connStr))
    for (int q = 0; q < 5; q++)
    {
        var id = Resume(storeWrapper);
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("resumed {0}", id));
    }

}

Activity GetDelayActivity(string addName = "")
{
    var name = new Variable<string>(string.Format("incr{0}", addName));
    Activity wf = new Sequence
    {
        DisplayName = "testDelayActivity",
        Variables = { name, new Variable<string>("CustomDataContext") },
        Activities =
            {
            new WriteLine
                {
                    Text = string.Format("before delay {0}", delayTime)
                },
                new Delay
                {
                    Duration = new InArgument<TimeSpan>(new TimeSpan(0, 0, delayTime))
                },
                new WriteLine
                {
                    Text = "after delay"
                }
            }
    };
    return wf;
}

Guid CreateAndRun(StoreWrapper sw)
{
    var idleEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    var wfApp = sw.GetApplication();

    wfApp.Idle = e => idleEvent.Set();
    wfApp.Aborted = e => idleEvent.Set();
    wfApp.Completed = e => idleEvent.Set();

    wfApp.Run();

    idleEvent.WaitOne(40 * 1000);
    var res = wfApp.Id;
    wfApp.Unload();
    return res;
}

Guid Resume(StoreWrapper sw)
{
    var res = Guid.Empty;

    var events = sw.GetStore().WaitForEvents(sw.Handle, new TimeSpan(0, 0, delayTime));

    if (events.Any(e => e.Equals(HasRunnableWorkflowEvent.Value)))
    {
        var idleEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        var obj = sw.GetApplication();
        try
        {
            obj.LoadRunnableInstance(); //instancenotready here if the same store has read all instances from DB and no delayed left

            obj.Idle = e => idleEvent.Set();
            obj.Completed = e => idleEvent.Set();

            obj.Run();

            idleEvent.WaitOne(40 * 1000);

            res = obj.Id;

            obj.Unload();
        }
        catch (InstanceNotReadyException)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("failed to resume {0} {1} {2}", obj.Id
                , obj.DefinitionIdentity == null ? null : obj.DefinitionIdentity.Name
                , obj.DefinitionIdentity == null ? null : obj.DefinitionIdentity.Version);
            foreach (var e in events)
            {
                Trace.TraceWarning("event {0}", e.Name);
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Here is store wrapper definition I'm using for test:

```
public class StoreWrapper : IDisposable
{
    Activity WfDefinition { get; set; }

    public static readonly XName WorkflowHostTypePropertyName = XNamespace.Get("urn:schemas-microsoft-com:System.Activities/4.0/properties").GetName("WorkflowHostType");
    public StoreWrapper(Activity wfDefinition, string connectionStr)
    {
        _store = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(connectionStr);

        HostTypeName = XName.Get(wfDefinition.DisplayName, "ttt.workflow");

        WfDefinition = wfDefinition;

    }

    SqlWorkflowInstanceStore _store;

    public SqlWorkflowInstanceStore GetStore()
    {
        if (Handle == null)
        {

            InitStore(_store, WfDefinition);
            Handle = _store.CreateInstanceHandle();

            var view = _store.Execute(Handle, new CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand
            {
                InstanceOwnerMetadata = { { WorkflowHostTypePropertyName, new InstanceValue(HostTypeName) } }
            }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

            _store.DefaultInstanceOwner = view.InstanceOwner;

            //Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} owns {1}", view.InstanceOwner.InstanceOwnerId, HostTypeName));
        }

        return _store;
    }

    protected virtual void InitStore(SqlWorkflowInstanceStore store, Activity wfDefinition)
    {
    }

    public InstanceHandle Handle { get; protected set; }

    XName HostTypeName { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Handle != null)
        {
            var deleteOwner = new DeleteWorkflowOwnerCommand();

            //Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} frees {1}", Store.DefaultInstanceOwner.InstanceOwnerId, HostTypeName));

            _store.Execute(Handle, deleteOwner, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            Handle.Free();
            Handle = null;

            _store = null;
        }
    }

    public WorkflowApplication GetApplication()
    {
        var wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(WfDefinition);
        wfApp.InstanceStore = GetStore();
        wfApp.PersistableIdle = e => PersistableIdleAction.Persist;

        Dictionary<XName, object> wfScope = new Dictionary<XName, object> { { WorkflowHostTypePropertyName, HostTypeName } };
        wfApp.AddInitialInstanceValues(wfScope);

        return wfApp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for the basic question. Hope you will get more attention. Actually, I think, there might be couple of reasons why your question receives less attention despite your `+150` bounty. (1) Not many people using `Workflow`, (2) You are asking for `Best Solution` which might be more suited question for Code Review rather than Stack Overflow, (3) This is rather minor, but your test code is pretty long without meaningful explanation (which is ok if people can really duplicate your issue directly from it, but otherwise will discourage the code reading). Hope you get your answer though...

Comment: the failing and not failing loops are doing two separate things , the wokring one you start a new StoreWrapper for each iteration. and the other one you reuse one StoreWrapper for each iteration.  it was quite sometime ago i used workflow but , seeing the code makes me think that your store wrapper is not a reusable object.  so you might just consider going with the working loop. or does it cause any other problems?

Comment: @Thorarins I can rewrite samples using plain SqlWorkflowInstanceStore but the problem will persist. I've seen samples in the web that uses the same SqlWorkflowInstanceStore instance to query WF database for ready to run workflows. I can create new instance inside the loop but I'm afraid that this will cause extra memory overhead and time delay.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not workflow foundation expert so my answer is based on the official examples from Microsoft. The first one is [WF4 host resumes delayed workflow (CSWF4LongRunningHost)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWF4LongRunningHost-5960e8d3) and the second is [Microsoft.Samples.AbsoluteDelay](http://wf4.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/resource/Sample%20code/WF_WCF_Samples/WF/Basic/Services/AbsoluteDelay/CS/AbsoluteDelay/Program.cs). In both samples you will find a code similar to yours i.e.:

```
try 
{
    wfApp.LoadRunnableInstance();
    ...
} 
catch (InstanceNotReadyException) 
{
    //Some logging
}
```

Taking this into account the answer is that you are right and the empty catch for `InstanceNotReadyException` is a good solution.